# How to prevent name from appearing unnecessarily on single authored elsarticle?

Tags: elsarticle

In a single authored article using elsarticle document class, the author's name appears unnecessarily after his email and url. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
\documentclass[final,times,letterpaper,authoryear,12pt]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Sample title
\tnoteref{t1}}
\tnotetext[t1]{Preliminary and incomplete.}

\author{John Doe\fnref{fn1}
}
\address{Bogus Department, Bogus University\par\vskip 18pt \textnormal{\normalsize{\today}}}
\fntext[fn1]{Contact: Bogus University, Bogus Department, 23 Grey Street, 3rd floor Fake City, USA.}
\ead{doe@gmail.com}
\ead[url]{https://johndoe.com/}
\begin{abstract}
Sample abstract
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a one-time hack, or do you want an "intelligent" handling or the one author vs multiple author situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't worry about the author addition as this is for submission to some journal.

However, a patch of the appropriate macros removes the "unnecessary name":

[image]

```
\documentclass[final,times,letterpaper,authoryear,12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\emailauthor}{(#2)}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\urlauthor}{(#2)}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Sample title
\tnoteref{t1}}
\tnotetext[t1]{Preliminary and incomplete.}

\author{John Doe\fnref{fn1}
}
\address{Bogus Department, Bogus University\par\vskip 18pt \textnormal{\normalsize{\today}}}
\fntext[fn1]{Contact: Bogus University, Bogus Department, 23 Grey Street, 3rd floor Fake City, USA.}
\ead{doe@gmail.com}
\ead[url]{https://johndoe.com/}
\begin{abstract}
Sample abstract
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While my answer is functionally equivalent, this should be the preferred approach.

Comment: @Werner "You shouldn't worry about the author addition as this is for submission to some journal": technically yes. But I like the way thinks look there so I have adapted to use it with all my articles.

Answer (score 4):

You can redefine the `\emailauthor` and `\urlauthor` macros. Looking at `elsarticle.cls`, these macros are called from `\ead`:

```
\gdef\emailauthor#1#2{\stepcounter{ead}%
    \g@addto@macro\@elseads{\raggedright%
    \let\corref\@gobble
    \eadsep\texttt{#1} (#2)\def\eadsep{\unskip,\space}}%
}
```

and

```
\def\urlauthor#1#2{\g@addto@macro\@elsuads{\let\corref\@gobble%
    \raggedright\eadsep\texttt{#1}\space(#2)%
    \def\eadsep{\unskip,\space}}%
}
```

Placing this in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\gdef\emailauthor#1#2{\stepcounter{ead}%
     \g@addto@macro\@elseads{\raggedright%
      \let\corref\@gobble
      \eadsep\texttt{#1}\def\eadsep{\unskip,\space}}%
}
\def\urlauthor#1#2{\g@addto@macro\@elsuads{\let\corref\@gobble%
    \raggedright\eadsep\texttt{#1}%
    \def\eadsep{\unskip,\space}}%
}
\makeatother
```

yields:

[image]

versus:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For fun, here is a more "intelligent" solution that can automatically change the behavior based on the number of authors added.

```
\documentclass[final,times,letterpaper,authoryear,12pt]{elsarticle}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \makeatletter
        %1. Define counter
        \newcounter{numberofauthors}
        %2. Modify \emailauthor and \urlauthor
        \pretocmd{\emailauthor}{\ifnum\value{numberofauthors}>1}{}{}
        \apptocmd{\emailauthor}{\else\stepcounter{ead}\g@addto@macro\@elseads{\raggedright\let\corref\@gobble\eadsep\texttt{#1}\def\eadsep{\unskip,\space}}\fi}{}{}
        \pretocmd{\urlauthor}{\ifnum\value{numberofauthors}>1}{}{}
        \apptocmd{\urlauthor}{\else\g@addto@macro\@elsuads{\let\corref\@gobble\raggedright\eadsep\texttt{#1}\def\eadsep{\unskip,\space}}\fi}{}{}
        %3. Modify \author
        \pretocmd{\author}{\addtocounter{numberofauthors}{1}}{}{}
        %4. Modify frontmatter
        \AtBeginEnvironment{frontmatter}{\makeatletter\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\setcounter{numberofauthors}{\expandafter\@arabic\thenumberofauthors}}\makeatother\setcounter{numberofauthors}{0}}
        \AtEndEnvironment{frontmatter}{\makeatletter\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\setcounter{numberofauthors}{\expandafter\@arabic\thenumberofauthors}}\makeatother}
    \makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Sample title
\tnoteref{t1}}
\tnotetext[t1]{Preliminary and incomplete.}
\author{John Doe\fnref{fn1}}
\address{Bogus Department, Bogus University}
\fntext[fn1]{Contact: Bogus University, Bogus Department, 23 Grey Street, 3rd floor Fake City, USA.}
\ead{doe@gmail.com}
\ead[url]{https://johndoe.com/}

\author{Jane Doe}
\address{Another Bogus Department, Another Bogus University}
\fntext[fn1]{Contact: Another Bogus University, Another Bogus Department, 23 Grey Street, 3rd floor Fake City, USA.}
\ead{janedoe@gmail.com}
\ead[url]{https://janedoe.com/}

\begin{abstract}
Sample abstract
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

Which yields:

[image: multiple authors]

If the entries related to Jane Doe are removed, the following is produced:

[image: single author]

**Explanation:**

The `elsarticle` class writes the `\emailauthor` and `urlauthor` commands to the `aux` file, which is then read in at the beginning of the document and these commands are executed, defining the `@elseads` and `@elsuads` macros to contain the email addresses and urls of the authors, respectively. With some surgery on `elsarticle.cls`, we can redefine `\emailauthor` and `\urlauthor` to exclude the name of the author if there is only one. These commands evaluate the number of authors courtesy of a new counter `numberofauthors`, the value of which is written *before* the `\emailauthor` and `\urlauthor` commands in the `aux` file.

**Step 1:** Add the `numberofauthors` counter.

`elsarticle.cls` defines an `author` counter, but its does not appear to be used as expected. Also, it is better to avoid conflicts by defining a new one.

```
\newcounter{numberofauthors}
```

**Step 2:** Make `\emailauthor` and `\urlauthor` dependent on `numberofauthors`.

This is accomplished by adding this to the preamble:

```
\pretocmd{\emailauthor}{\ifnum\value{numberofauthors}>1}{}{}
\apptocmd{\emailauthor}{\else\stepcounter{ead}\g@addto@macro\@elseads{\raggedright\let\corref\@gobble\eadsep\texttt{#1}\def\eadsep{\unskip,\space}}\fi}{}{}
\pretocmd{\urlauthor}{\ifnum\value{numberofauthors}>1}{}{}
\apptocmd{\urlauthor}{\else\g@addto@macro\@elsuads{\let\corref\@gobble\raggedright\eadsep\texttt{#1}\def\eadsep{\unskip,\space}}\fi}{}{}
```

The `\pretocmd{\emailauthor}` and `\apptocmd{\emailauthor}` calls change the definition of `\emailauthor` from

```
\gdef\emailauthor#1#2{\stepcounter{ead}%
     \g@addto@macro\@elseads{\raggedright%
      \let\corref\@gobble
      \eadsep\texttt{#1} (#2)\def\eadsep{\unskip,\space}}%
}
```

to (*formatted here for readability):

```
\def\emailauthor#1#2{
    \ifnum\value{numberofauthors}>1
        \stepcounter{ead}%
        \g@addto@macro\@elseads{\raggedright%
        \let\corref\@gobble
        \eadsep\texttt{#1} (#2)\def\eadsep{\unskip,\space}}%
    \else
        \stepcounter{ead}%
        \g@addto@macro\@elseads{\raggedright%
        \let\corref\@gobble
        \eadsep\texttt{#1}\def\eadsep{\unskip,\space}}%
    \fi}%
```

`\pretocmd{\urlauthor}` and `\apptocmd{\urlauthor}` similarly change the definition of `\urlauthor`.

**Step 3:** Increment `numberofauthors` whenever `\author` is called.

This is accomplished by:

```
\pretocmd{\author}{\addtocounter{numberofauthors}{1}}{}{}
```

Which redefines `\author` from

```
\def\author{\@ifnextchar[{\@@author}{\@author}}
```

to

```
\def\author{\addtocounter{numberofauthors}{1}\@ifnextchar[{\@@author}{\@author}}
```

**Step4:** Preserve the `numberofauthors` in the `aux` file.

This is accomplished by

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{frontmatter}{\makeatletter\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\setcounter{numberofauthors}{\expandafter\@arabic\thenumberofauthors}}\makeatother\setcounter{numberofauthors}{0}}
\AtEndEnvironment{frontmatter}{\makeatletter\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\setcounter{numberofauthors}{\expandafter\@arabic\thenumberofauthors}}\makeatother}
```

which is the same as:

```
\begin{frontmatter}
    \makeatletter
        \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\setcounter{numberofauthors}{\expandafter\@arabic\thenumberofauthors}}
    \makeatother
    \setcounter{numberofauthors}{0}

     %Normal title and author definitions

    \makeatletter
        \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\setcounter{numberofauthors}{\expandafter\@arabic\thenumberofauthors}}
    \makeatother
\end{frontmatter}
```

Behavior of the `\setcounter` pair is best explained by showing relevant portions of the `aux` file after each run:

First run (no previous `aux` file):

```
\setcounter{numberofauthors}{0}
\emailauthor{doe@gmail.com}{John Doe\fnref {fn1}}
\urlauthor{https://johndoe.com/}{John Doe\fnref {fn1}}
\setcounter{numberofauthors}{1}
```

On the second run, the `numberofauthors` counter is 0 when `\emailauthor` and `\urlauthor` are evaluated, yielding email addresses and urls without authors. Following the second run (using the above `aux` file) the `aux` file contains:

```
\setcounter{numberofauthors}{1}
\emailauthor{doe@gmail.com}{John Doe\fnref {fn1}}
\urlauthor{https://johndoe.com/}{John Doe\fnref {fn1}}
\setcounter{numberofauthors}{1}
```

This remains the same in subsequent runs, resulting in the desired behavior for `\emailauthor` and `\urlauthor`.